# CUD Methods won't fire

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to use RIA Services with Repository pattern, Every CRUD operations worked perfectly until I implemented the repositories. Now only query and Submit methods are working. I tried the methods both with and without Query, Insert, Update and Delete attributes.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

```
[LinqToEntitiesDomainServiceDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyEntityModelContainer))]
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class MyService : DomainService
{
    internal IUnitOfWork ObjectContext { get; private set; }

    public MyService(IUnitOfWork context)
    {
        this.ObjectContext = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.BusinessEntities.OfType<Employee>();
    }

    public void InsertEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        this.ObjectContext.BusinessEntities.AddObject(employee);
    }

    public void UpdateEmployee(Employee currentEmployee)
    {
        this.ObjectContext.BusinessEntities.AttachAsModified(currentEmployee,     this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentEmployee));
    }

    public void DeleteEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if( (employee.EntityState == EntityState.Detached) )
        {
            this.ObjectContext.BusinessEntities.Attach(employee);
        }

        this.ObjectContext.BusinessEntities.DeleteObject(employee);
    }

    public override bool Submit(ChangeSet changeSet)
    {
        this.ObjectContext.Commit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overrode the Submit method by mistake.